# What can be said about this metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I've developed a metric that seems to work pretty well for predicting the magnitude of supernovae.$$a\left(t\right)=\frac{t^2}{t_0^2}$$$$ds^2=i^2\left(c_3+A_3 t \right)^2 dt^2+\left(\frac{1+a\left(t\right)}{2} \right)^2\left(dr^2+\left(\frac{sin\left(r\sqrt{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}} \right)^2 \left(d\theta^2+sin^2 \theta\space d \phi^2 \right) \right)$$Where $c_3$ is a constant velocity, $A_3$ is a constant acceleration, and $t_0$ is a constant time and $t<t_0$.  What can we say about this geometry?

For example, it appears that there's an acceleration at every point on this manifold.  So is this manifold locally flat anywhere?

It's obviously not Lorentzian, is there a category for this kind of a metric?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be an FRW metric in a positively (spatially) curved universe? What other characterizations are you seeking? This is a bit of a broad question.

Comment: FRW is $$ds^2=i^2\left(c t \right)^2 dt+a(t)^2\left(dr^2+\left(\frac{sin\left(r\sqrt{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}} \right)^2 \left(d\theta^2+sin^2 \theta\space d \phi^2 \right) \right)$$They only thing they have in common is that they're metrics that describe geometries. In FRW space, objects at rest remain at rest.  In the given metric, they accelerate.

Comment: The metrics are exactly identical, mod a "conformal factor" of $(c+At)^2$. Metrics that are off by a conformal factor are considered conformally equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by Lorentzian? I always understood it to mean not positive definite, which the metric is not since its signature is $(-+++)$

Comment: It means a lot of things, but for this metric, Lorentzian means objects at rest, remain at rest.  Objects in motion, remain in motion. That the spacetime is essentially flat in an infinitesimally small volume.  The given metric doesn't appear to be flat locally.  At every point in the manifold, I find an acceleration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that for me. I think you have a few concepts mixed up. "Objects at rest staying at rest" aka an "inertial" frame is a property of geodesic observers, not the geometry of the space. A uniformly accelerating frame such as Rindler coordinates $$ds^2 =-x^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$$ has the same weirdness you describe, but all components of its Riemann tensor vanish. Under the coordinate change $2A\tau = (c_3 + At)^2$ your metric is$$ds^2=-d\tau^2+f(\tau)(\cdots)$$ which is exactly FRW. A scaling in one variable cannot change the underlying geometry of the space.

Comment: It definitely is Rindler coordinates and the way you can tell is that the null rays are the characteristic logarithmic curves. The only for sure way to tell if a metric is flat is to calculate the components of the Riemann tensor. In general you cannot tell if a space is curved or not by "looking" at a metric.

Comment: The answer to your question is more complicated because it doesn't make sense, and I would double check whatever source you are learning nonstandard terminology from. On the one hand every manifold is "locally flat" because each point has a tangent space. On the other, curvature is intrinisc and does not vanish even if you look at "small enough" spaces. Even the Ricci scalar for FRW which you called locally flat is nonzero at every point, hence my confusion on what you actually mean. Your metric is a reparametrized time variable of FRW, take that to mean what you will.

Comment: That's not a direct product of the geometry. The equation you describe is the geodesic equation. You can find geodesics for almost any metric you write down.

Comment: @NinadMunshi - I'm afraid I didn't appreciate your answer the first time I read it.  Is it possible for you to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028275/how-do-i-re-parameterize-this-metric-to-make-it-look-more-like-flrw and complete the thought you started with $2\space A\tau = (c_3 + A\space t)^2$?  It would help me a great deal to see the entire formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the coordinate transformation $2A_3\tau = (c_3+A_3t)^2\implies 2A_3d\tau = 2A_3(c_3+A_3t)dt$ we have that your metric becomes

$$-\left[(c_3+A_3t)dt\right]^2 + \tilde{a}(t)\Bigr(\cdots\Bigr) = -d\tau^2+\tilde{a}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2A_3\tau}-c_3}{A_3}\right)\Biggr(\cdots\Biggr) \equiv -d\tau^2 + \tilde{a}'(\tau)\Bigr(\cdots\Bigr)$$

FRW with a rescaled time parameter. In other words it's just constituting a different coordinate system on the same underlying geometry, just like how imposing spherical coordinates on a flat space does not magically curve it.

---

You mentioned that this was good at predicting some kind of behavior with supernovas, let's analyze this further. In the notation from my work we have the formula for the scaling parameter is

$$\tilde{a}'(\tau) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{(\sqrt{2A_3\tau}-c_3)^2}{A_3^2t_0^2}\right) = k_0 + k_{1/2}\sqrt{\tau} + k_1\tau$$

Notice that at different times $\tau$ the growth of this scale factor is either dominated by the square root term or the linear term. Square root growth is associated with a radiation dominated universe (filled with highly energetic, relativistically moving particles) and linear growth is associated with a "curvature dominated" universe (that is, an empty universe with extreme spatial curvature).

Comment: _"just like how imposing spherical coordinates on a flat space does not magically curve it"_ Yes. this.